# Mmap a large 1TB file and write 1's to it?

Tags: c, file-io, posix, mmap, memset

I am very new to mmap and memset. I have been assigned a task to create a large file (1TB) and write 1's to it as we are trying to understand the performance.

Now from what I understand, I can basically fallocate a file with 1Tb, then in a C function, I can mmap it with PROT_READ, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED and then memset that mmap'ed pointed with memset, like this :

```
int fd = open(FILEPATH, O_RDWE, (mode_t)0700);
size_t data_length = 1000000000000;
char *data = (char*)mmap(NULL, data_length, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_POPULATE, fd , 0);
memset(data, '1', data_length);
```

Is this correct? 
Do I need to sync or anything to make this data persistent?

If so, I'm basically writing a 1TB file then **why does my function run within split seconds**. 
I've tried to cat the output file and there indeed are 1's, its just that my terminal craps out after a few seconds, but the data is actually getting written.

Am I doing this correctly or should I actually go and write data to memory rather than memset. If so, how should I do it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You do not check whether `mmap()` returned `MAP_FAILED`.

Comment: Closing the file when you're done seems to make sense.

Comment: Hi Eof, I do check for MAP_FAILED right after the mmap call.

Comment: No, you do not - you get the data back and then `memset` it

Comment: If OP got MAP_FAILED the memset would have segfaulted anyway, so that's not what happened.

Comment: So if you reboot your machine, and look at the file size, is it actually 1TB?

Comment: You *are* compiling for 64-bit right?